# How to hide certain menu like PAYMENT SETTINGS based on product ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

How to hide certain menu like PAYMENT SETTINGS based on product ID that subscriber pay for?

I know how to hide button based on the product ID, but I don't know how to hide certain menu based on product ID.

[image: Can check image here]

Please help because I'm stuck.

```
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {

    $is_my_product = false;
    $specific_products = array( 108150 , 108154 , 108144 , 108157  );
    if ( sizeof( $subscription_items = $subscription->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $subscription_items as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $specific_products ) ) {
                $is_my_product = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !$is_my_product ) return $actions;

    foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
        switch ( $action_key ) {
            case 'Cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                break;
            default: 
                error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                break;
            }
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

- This code is to hide certain button in subscription based on product ID.
- I want to hide certain menu like PAYMENT SETTINGS based on product ID.
  [image: Can check image here.]